# integration tests with kafka in c#

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, integration-testing

I have a library to publish and consume messages from kafka and I am trying to do integration tests on it, but I have a big issue as the consumer "does not" connect properly.

So I reduced (for the test) to the next consumer:

```
private void FakeConsumer(string kafkaServer)
{
    var config = GetSettings(kafkaServer);
    using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
    {
        c.Subscribe(Topic);

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) =>
        {
            e.Cancel = true; 
            cts.Cancel();
        };

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Consumed message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                }
                catch (ConsumeException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {e.Error.Reason}");

                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Ensure the consumer leaves the group cleanly and final offsets are committed.
            c.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

then in my integration test I ran it as background thread as you can see:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test()
{
    new Thread(() => FakeConsumer()) { IsBackground = true }.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Publisher<Event> publisher = new Publisher<Event>(args);

    Event ev = new Event();
    await publisher.PublishAsync(ev, Topic);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    
    Assert.Single(MessageHandler.Messages);
}
```

Note: I removed it for the post, but the code has a "messagehandler" which Stores in memory the read message.

I also added some `Thread.Sleep` on the main test so the topic gets created and there is no "overlaping" between both actions.

the publish code `publisher.PublishAsync` works perfectly as I can see the message in kafdrop.

The issue is that the code never passes `var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);` the thread is stuck in there.

What should I do to receive the information or to allow the BackgroundTrhead to receive the information in `var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);`?

Final note: if I split the code into two different console applications it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add ```.SetPartitionsAssignedHandler((c, partitions) { var committed = c.Committed(partitions, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); Console.WriteLine($"Assigned partitions: [{string.Join(", ",  });``` on your ConsumerBuilder And check if partitions are assigned correctly?

Comment: @rytisk thanks for the reply, I added the code and the breakpoint does not stop in there and I cannot see any related output.  (the Console.WriteLine)

Comment: that means you are not subscribing to the topic correctly, so you are not getting any messages. You should double check your configurations. Maybe you set the wrong broker address or the wrong topic name?

Comment: @rytisk I am using variables for the topic and the broker so those should be fine

Comment: Are there no other consumers (within the same consumer group) trying to read that same topic?

Comment: @rytisk no, this is just me on my local machine against docker in my machine too